# How to convert hours to seconds in carbon PHP API extension

Tags: laravel, datetime, php-carbon, datetime-conversion

I want to convert `"2 hours 11 mins"`(string)
to seconds in carbon
is there's any way convert that string format into seconds in carbon?
I am stuck with this, couldn't find a solution yet
Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Carbon` has a useful `modify()` function:

https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub

This function can handle a number of "magic" durations to change a Date to another one. Since `Carbon` works with time stamps, you'll need a base and an modified one, then compare them:

```
$base = Carbon\Carbon::now();                         // 2020-11-03 19:04:49.140462 UTC (+00:00)
$modified = $base->copy()->modify('2 hours 11 mins'); // 2020-11-03 21:15:49.140462 UTC (+00:00),
$diff = $base->diffInSeconds($modified);              // 7860
```

Note: the string passed to `modify()` can fail, but you'll receive an error if it does.

Answer (score 2):

there is a third way:

```
use Carbon\CarbonInterval;


 $intervalue=CarbonInterval::make("2 hours 11 mins");

$intervalueInSeconds= $intervalue->totalSeconds;
```

Comment: @Wishwajith Milinda I recommend you mark this answer as the solution, this is more explicit and readable and avoid having to create 2 dates.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need carbon to do it. Use native php functions.

1. Use regex function to get `$hours` and `$minutes`.
2. `$seconds = $hours*3600 + $minutes*60;`

Comment: That solution also fulfill, but I am looking for carbon extension thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function in PHP :

```
$t = strtotime("2 hours 11 mins");
echo (time() - $t) . " seconds ago";
// -7860 seconds ago
```